# Query SQL retornando registros duplicados

Tags: mysql, sql, query, select, join

Tenho duas tabelas (`adwords_performance` e `analytics_transaction`) e preciso fazer um `SELECT` somando as colunas `adwords_performance.clicks`, `adwords_performance.impressions` e `analytics_transaction.transaction_revenue`.

Quando eu faço o `SELECT` ele me retorna valores de errados em `adwords_performance.clicks` e `adwords_performance.impressions`.

```
SELECT
adwords_performance.date,
Sum(adwords_performance.clicks) AS clicks,
Sum(adwords_performance.impressions) AS impressions,
Sum(analytics_transaction.transaction_revenue) AS revenue
FROM
adwords_performance
LEFT JOIN analytics_transaction 
ON analytics_transaction.date = adwords_performance.date AND
analytics_transaction.adwords_id = adwords_performance.adwords_id AND
analytics_transaction.adwords_campaign_id = adwords_performance.adwords_campaign_id
WHERE
adwords_performance.date = '2015-03-01' AND
adwords_performance.adwords_id = '0123456789'
GROUP BY
adwords_performance.date
```

Resultado:

```
+------------+--------+-------------+---------+
| date       | clicks | impressions | revenue |
+------------+--------+-------------+---------+
| 2015-03-01 |    465 |       21017 | 1937.71 |
+------------+--------+-------------+---------+
```

Resultado que era para ser retornado:

```
+------------+--------+-------------+---------+
| date       | clicks | impressions | revenue |
+------------+--------+-------------+---------+
| 2015-03-01 |    364 |       18577 | 1937.71 |
+------------+--------+-------------+---------+
```

Tabelas:

```
mysql> describe adwords_performance;
+--------------------------------+---------------------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field                          | Type                            | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------------------------+---------------------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                             | int(20) unsigned                | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| adwords_id                     | bigint(255) unsigned            | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| adwords_campaign_id            | bigint(255) unsigned            | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| campaign_network_type          | varchar(255)                    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| date                           | date                            | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| week                           | date                            | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| week_day                       | varchar(25)                     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| clicks                         | int(255)                        | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| impressions                    | int(255)                        | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| cost                           | int(255)                        | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| av_position                    | decimal(2,1)                    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| clicks_converted               | int(255)                        | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| estimated_converted            | int(255)                        | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| estimated_converted_rate       | decimal(10,2) unsigned zerofill | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| clicks_converted_assisted      | int(255)                        | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| impressions_converted_assisted | int(255)                        | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| lost_budget                    | varchar(255)                    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| clicks_invalid                 | int(255)                        | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+--------------------------------+---------------------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+


mysql> describe analytics_transaction;
+----------------------+----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field                | Type                 | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------------------+----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                   | int(15) unsigned     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| analytics_id         | bigint(255) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| date                 | date                 | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| time                 | int(2)               | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| source               | varchar(255)         | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| medium               | varchar(255)         | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| city                 | varchar(255)         | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| adwords_id           | bigint(255) unsigned | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| adwords_campaign_id  | bigint(255) unsigned | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| transaction_id       | bigint(255) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| transaction_revenue  | double(10,2)         | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| transaction_shipping | double(10,2)         | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| transaction_tax      | double(10,2)         | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| product_quantity     | int(10)              | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+----------------------+----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Comment: Não encontrei nada de errado no seu select. O que você fez pra acreditar que o resultado esperado realmente é o esperado?

Comment: O problema está no JOIN com os campos data. Para você ter o resultado esperado, as tabelas à direita (estas conectadas por JOIN) deveriam ter um único registro para cada registro da tabela principal. Como na tabela à direita você tem mais de uma ocorrência para a mesma data, o JOIN pelo campo data não vai funcionar como você espera. Você precisa arrumar outro jeito de ligar estas tabelas que não pelo campo data.

Comment: A tabela adwords_performance deve ser agregada em uma tabela virtual ou view e esta e que unir com as demais tabelas , os valores agregados devem estar no agrupamento.

Comment: @Caffé Entendi, você teria em mente alguma maneira de ligar essas tabelas com a estrutura que citei acima de tabelas? Não consigo imaginar outra maneira. Efetuei um teste mudando o campo 'date' para um 'id' e concatenando com JOIN as duas tabelas e ainda aparenta o mesmo erro!

Comment: @JeffersonSilva Eu faço dois SELECT separado um na tabela adwords_performance e outro no analytics_transaction "faço isso para ver realmente o select esta retornando os valores corretos" e ele me retorna aquele valor como citei acima de 364 clicks e 18577 impressions

Comment: @JoãoGabrielPellissari Não tenho nenhuma sugestão de JOIN no momento porque não analisei muito suas tabelas (isso toma tempo). Se você puder criar um exemplo mínimo verificável no sqlfiddle com certeza nós ajudaremos a resolver o problema rapidamente. http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: @Caffé Como você pediu é isso fiz uma query envolvendo todas as tabelas que eu utilizo http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/48bec/4

Comment: O problema é que tem mais de um registro na `analytics_transaction` pra cada `adwords_performance`. Coloquei uma resposta com o método que achei mais efetivo pra resolver o problema

Answer (score 1):

O problema é que a sua tabela `analytics_transaction` possui mais de um registro por `adwords_performance` multiplicando os cliques. Você pode resolver isso fazendo uma `subquery` para obter os resultados desejados desta tabela, eliminado o join. Porém como é necessário que todos os campos estejam no `GROUP BY` você deve utilizar um `select` baseado no resultado da `query` anterior. O resultado é o seguinte:

```
SELECT x.date,
       SUM(x.clicks) as clicks,
       SUM(x.impressions) as impressions,
       SUM(x.revenue) as revenue
  FROM (SELECT ap.date,
               ap.clicks AS clicks,
               ap.impressions AS impressions,
               (SELECT SUM(at.transaction_revenue)
                 FROM analytics_transaction at
                WHERE at.adwords_id = ap.adwords_id
                  AND at.adwords_campaign_id = ap.adwords_campaign_id
                  AND at.date = at.date) AS revenue
          FROM adwords_performance ap
         WHERE ap.date = '2015-03-01'
           AND ap.adwords_id = '0123456789') x
 GROUP BY x.date
```